# Cant see widgets in QMainWindow pyqt6

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I've created a window that should theoretically behave as a splash screen for my application. I've designed the layout using designer, but when trying to launch it the right way all I get is a blank screen.

None of the widgets are rendered.

```py
import sys 
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from thinclient.ui.launcher.splashScreen import Ui_MainWindow as splashScreen_MainWindow
import time

class SplashScreen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = splashScreen_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        for i in range(20,101,20):
            # self.ui.progressBar.setValue(i)
            time.sleep(2)
```

This is the pyuic generated file that works fine when launched standalone but weird when launching by a submodule in the python package.

```py
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui/splashScreen.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt6 UI code generator 6.4.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic6 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 380, 67, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: You shouldn't use blocking functions (such as `time.sleep`) in a GUI, as they completely blocks the event loop preventing **anything** to happen (including properly displaying the contents of the UI). If you want to call a function at specific intervals, use QTimer.

Comment: Without the time.sleep the window does not load all together, I want it to wait while a qthread performs some tasks. How should I test this solution? Like a normal window I expect it to render all the widgets at least. Instead the execution of the application just continues

Comment: If "the window does not load all together" without `time.sleep`, then you're doing something wrong, because, as already said, you should ***NOT*** use blocking functions in the UI. You also never specified that you were using threads, and even in that case you do **not** use time.sleep to wait for their completion. You cannot expect to see the widgets because it's exactly time.sleep that prevents it. If you need to wait for other threads, use QThread and custom signals. Do some research on the subject, as there are literally thousands of resources about it.

Comment: I'm using qthread but I'm afraid it's blocking the main thread, can't find too many resources for the same. Do you have any? I'm also using signals by the way.

Comment: Please take a look at another question of mine, apparently the problem is something completely different.